# How to delay the response of my Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, response, delay

I am working on a Web API project and that has an Artist Web API Controller. On there, there is the `api/artist` method that is a `GET` for all artists.

When making the call to this method, I would like a 3 second delay before I serve the data, how can I achieve this?

**CODE**

```
public class ArtistController : ApiController
{
    private GlContext db = new GlContext();

    // GET api/Artist
    public IQueryable<Artist> GetArtists()
    {
        return db.Artists;
    }
}
```

I know that you wouldn't want to do this in a production environment, but I am playing with preloaders, and in order to test them properly I need to introduce this delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is just for testing you can always go for `Thread.Sleep(3000)`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx